# javascript - comparing arrays elements

Tags: javascript

I've got an array that could have 4 digits elements or less (from html select)
for example some possible variants of `myArray`:

```
myArray = ['1']
myArray = ['4'] 
myArray = ['2', '3']
myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] 
etc...
```

now I've got an object that has possible variants of `myArray`
for example some possible variants of `myObject`:

```
myObject = [
   {active: false, forArrays:['2','4']},
   {active: false, forArrays:['2,3,4','2,4']},
   {active: false, forArrays:['2','1,4']},
   {active: false, forArrays:['2']},
]
```

I want to change active to true if `myArray` is exact the same that one of the `forArrays` variants.

How can I do that? Should I keep `forArrays` an array as it is or should it be changed to an object to make this problem easier to solve?

Comment: So your question is how to check for array equality?

Comment: @Amy that's right

Comment: So the only one of your examples that would pass is `myArray = ['4']`?

Comment: @vol7ron yes - in this case, and first element will be activated

Comment: @gileneusz will `myArray` ever have a comma-delimited set of numbers like your second object (e.g., `'2,3,4'`)?  Or are you expecting `['2','3','4']` to match that case?

Comment: If your `myArray = ['1','4']` will it match your second-to-last object?

Comment: no, myArray elements could have only numbers 1-4 in this case, like "1", "2", "3", "4"

Comment: @vol7ron arrays that could match second last object are only: myArray = ['1','4'] and myArray = ['2'] and myArray = ['4','1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comments, you can sort and join by commas and compare to each forArray element:

```js
let myArray = ['1','4']

let myObject = [
   {active: false, forArrays:['2','4']},
   {active: false, forArrays:['2,3,4','2,4']},
   {active: false, forArrays:['2','1,4']},
   {active: false, forArrays:['2']},
]

let myArrayString = myArray.sort().join(',');

myObject.forEach( obj => 
  obj.active = obj.forArrays.some( el => 
    myArrayString === el.split(',').sort().join(',') 
  ) 
)

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: thank you for this solution, I will check it now

Comment: I'm trying to understand what this part of code is doing(?):
`val=>{ val = val.split(',').sort().join(',')`

Comment: @gileneusz `val` is the element of your `forArray`.  So `'4,2,1,3'` will become `'1,2,3,4'`, making string comparison more accurate

Comment: @gileneusz updated using `some` and always setting the active — see if that makes more sense for you

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code

Comment: There's only 3 lines ^_^

Comment: started to learn full stack 4 months ago ;) and started coding today 14 hours ago ;)

Comment: First split string: `'2,4,3'.split(',')` => `['2','4','3']`  Then sort values:  `['2','4','3'].sort()` => `['2','3','4']`  Then rebuild string: `['2','3','4'].join(',')` => `'2,3,4'`

Comment: That's all done because `myArray.sort().join(',');` so in the example `['1','4']` will become `'1,4'`.  We can trust that the value we're checking and comparing to will always be in sorted order so an exact match can be done with string comparison

Comment: `obj =>` not `obj => {`?

Comment: a block (curly brace container) is only necessary when there's more than one statement.  Otherwise it will be the return value of the arrow function

Comment: at this moment not working :) I need sleep

Comment: The example clearly works.

Comment: I do not doubt about it :)

Comment: I just prefer spaghetti code, It's more clean and readable

Comment: Ahh I guess readability improves with familiarity

Comment: It works! the only thing I've changed was: `myObject[i].active = obj.forArrays.some( el => ...` because I was in right Object already thanks to for loop. Thank you for help!

Comment: oh wait: `myObject[i].active = myObject[i].forArrays.some( el => ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the objects and check if `forArrays` contains comma separated value.

For unsorted values, you could sort them in advanced.

```js
function update(numbers) {
    function asc(a, b) { return a - b; }

    var values = numbers.slice().sort(asc).join();
    myObject.forEach(function (o) {
        if (o.forArrays.some(a => a.split(',').sort(asc).join() === values)) {
            o.active = true;
        }
    });
}

var myObject = [{ active: false, forArrays: ['2', '4'] }, { active: false, forArrays: ['2,3,4', '2,4'] }, { active: false, forArrays: ['2', '1,4'] }];

update(['1']);         // no change
console.log(myObject);

update(['2']);
update(['2', '4']);
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems ok, but I cannot assume the same order... That is why I consider to change forArrays values to separate objects/arrays...

Comment: sorry for not responding to your edit, I was quite tired yesterday I and focused on vol7ron answer first. I see your answer is also correct and could be used to solve my problem. Thanks for posting it!